# only that checkbox are selected those are are in front of us

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have a button to select all check boxes but i have a issue only that check boxes are selected whose are in front of us on scrolling down other check boxes are not selected

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.callblockerapp.R;
import com.utills.DbHelper;

public class AddFromContacts extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ContactsAdapter ma;
ListView lv;
private Button select, btnCancelFromContacts, btnAllFromContacts;

DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_from_contacts);

    getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ContactlistView);
    ma = new ContactsAdapter();
    lv.setAdapter(ma);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    // adding
    select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getSelected);
    btnCancelFromContacts = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.btnCancelFromContacts));
    btnCancelFromContacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
            String name, phoneNumber;
            for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

            {
                if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                    // checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                    // checkedcontacts.append("\n");
                    name = name1.get(i).toString();
                    phoneNumber = phno1.get(i).toString();
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-", "");
                    Log.e("", "Checked Name :- " + name
                            + "\nChecked Phone Number :- " +             phoneNumber);
                    db.addBlockedNumber(phoneNumber, name);

                    finish();

                } else {

                }
            }

            // Toast.makeText(AddFromContacts.this, checkedcontacts,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    btnAllFromContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAllFromContacts);
    btnAllFromContacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
                ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup) lv.getChildAt(i);
                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) item
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            //  if (!checkbox.isChecked()) {
                    checkbox.setChecked(true);
                    btnAllFromContacts.setText("Uncheck All");
        //      } else if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
        //          checkbox.setChecked(false);
        //          btnAllFromContacts.setText("Select All");
        //      }

            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ma.toggle(arg2);
}

public void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                    + " ASC");
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones
                .getString(phones
                          .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        name1.add(name);
        phno1.add(phoneNumber);

    }

    phones.close();
}

class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView name, txtNumber;
    CheckBox cb;

    ContactsAdapter() {
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) AddFromContacts.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_from_contacts_row, null);
        txtNumber = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
        name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
        cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        txtNumber.setText("Name :" + name1.get(position));
        name.setText("Phone No :" + phno1.get(position));
        cb.setTag(position);
        cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return vi;
    }

    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
}
}
```

xml file add_from_contacts.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ContactlistView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ffbdbdbd"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="2.5dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAllFromContacts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Select All"
        android:textSize="14.0dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getSelected"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Add Contact"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="14.0dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancelFromContacts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textSize="14.0dip" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

another xml file add_from_contacts_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtNumber" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest an easy way to do that? Suppose I have a global variable for `class AddFromContacts` as,

```
public static boolean checked=false;
```

now, inside the button click (Button to select/deselect all), leave the loop you wrote as it is. Include the following.

```
if(checked)
   checked=false;
else
   checked=true;
```

Then inside Adapter `getView()`,

```
cb.setChecked(AddFromContacts.checked);
```

Eg: worked for me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView lv;
Button b1;
boolean checked=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Myadapter adapter=new Myadapter();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checked)
                checked=false;
            else
                checked=true;
             for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup) lv.getChildAt(i);
                    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) item
                            .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                        checkbox.setChecked(checked);
             }
        }
    });
}



class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter{
    CheckBox cb;
     LayoutInflater mInflater;

     public Myadapter() {
         mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 15;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            cb.setTag(position);
            cb.setChecked(checked);
        return vi;
    }

}


}
```

Also, I can see a method **`public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked)`**. If you meant to call this, change the code to **`setChecked(position,mCheckStates.get(position, false));`**

Comment: as i check it is not working in my code at least at the time of scrolling those check boxes are not unchecked which are checked but after using your code at the time of scrolling that are unchecked which i checked using select all button

Comment: Then add a Log before .setChecked() to check the value of `AddFromContacts.checked`. Make sure it is 'true'.

Comment: i have already checked it before posting question to stack over flow

Comment: I think the problem is with `mCheckStates`. I've updated answer that illustrate my logic. Its working good.